# Java graphics add method

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I'm trying to create a networked poker server client program, I'm currently writing the client side which includes the graphics part, However when I try to add a component to a JPanel in my code when a certain condition is met in the run method, add method doesn't seem to work, however other methods that manipulates the JPanel under the same condition works.

```
public class PokerClient {

BufferedReader in;
PrintWriter out;
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Poker");

JPanel playerHandPanel;

String serverAddress = "localhost";
String playerName;

Card playerHand1, playerHand2;


public PokerClient() {

    // Layout GUI
    frame.setSize(1100, 700);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    playerHandPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    playerHandPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300)); 
    playerHandPanel.add(new CardComponent(new Card(3, Suit.CLUB))); //it works here
    playerHandPanel.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(playerHandPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Prompt for and return the desired screen name.
 */
private String getName() {

    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        frame,
        "Choose a screen name:",
        "Screen name selection",
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

private Card constructCard(String line){
     int seperator = line.indexOf('/');
     int cardNum = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, seperator));
     Card card;
     if(line.substring(seperator+1).startsWith("S")){
       card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.SPADE);
     } else if(line.substring(seperator+1).startsWith("C")){
       card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.CLUB);
     } else if(line.substring(seperator+1).startsWith("D")){
       card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.DIAMOND);
     } else{
       card = new Card(cardNum, Suit.HEART);
     }
     System.out.println(card.toString());
     return card;
}

/**
 * Connects to the server then enters the processing loop.
 */
private void run() throws IOException {

    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddress, 9050);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    // Process all messages from server, according to the protocol.
    while (true) {
        String line = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.startsWith("SUBMITNAME")) {
 //             String name = getName();
 //             playerName = name;
//                out.println(name);
        } else if (line.startsWith("p1")) {
            playerHandPanel.add(new CardComponent(new Card(4, Suit.SPADE)));//this doesn't work i can't figure out why
            playerHandPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);//this worked
            playerHandPanel.add(new JLabel("is this added"));//this doesn't work either
            playerHandPanel.repaint();
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PokerClient client = new PokerClient();
    client.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    client.frame.setVisible(true);
    client.run();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems jump out:

- You're not calling `revalidate()` on the playerHandPanel after adding or removing a component -- probably a major contributor to your problem.
- You're constraining the playerHandPanel's size artificially
- And not putting it into a JScrollPane
- Your code flaunts Swing threading rules by making major Swing component state changes off of the Swing event thread or EDT
- You're using a constraining layout, `new GridLayout(1, 2)`

Possible solutions:

- Yes, do call `revalidate()` on the playerHandPanel after adding or removing a component. This will tell its layout managers to do their thing.
- If you want to use GridLayout, do so in a more flexible way, such as, `new GridLayout(1, 0)` or `new GridLayout(1, 0)`, depending on if you want to specify the number of columns or rows (the `0` meaning a variable number of columns or rows)
- Consider using a JList or JTable, two components that are much easier to add things to.
- Do learn and follow Swing threading rules, including only making Swing state changes (such as adding or removing components, changing background color...) on the Swing event thread.

Comment: thank you that worked, and where can I find Swing threading rules? I'm teaching myself how to code so everything I know is based of bits and pieces from websites like this one.

Comment: @Mike: please have a look at [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)